# Redirect URL from Edit Form

Tags: url, redirect

Is it possible to redirect a URL from the Edit Form page?

I've read something about changing the source url, but it doesn't seem to be working for me.

Currently, when the user enters in information and presses save, the page goes back to the main list which they do not need to see.